# How to make a class a component in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in Java programming so I do not know if I may be using the correct terms here. Basically, I have an assignment to program a little applet that changes the color of the background to whatever of the 4 color buttons is pressed. I was given a sample code with ActionListener and was told to use MouseListener to implement it.

I was able to successfully program it to work and then the requirements changed. Below is my current code that works (before the requirements changed).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private JButton abutton, bbutton, cbutton, dbutton;

    public ButtonPanel(){
        abutton = new JButton("Cyan");
        bbutton = new JButton("Orange");
        cbutton = new JButton("Magenta");
        dbutton = new JButton("Yellow");

        add(abutton);
        add(bbutton);
        add(cbutton);
        add(dbutton);

    /* register the specific event handler into each button */
        abutton.addMouseListener(this);
        bbutton.addMouseListener(this);
        cbutton.addMouseListener(this);
        dbutton.addMouseListener(this);
    }

/* implementation for the Mouse Event  */

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source == abutton) setBackground(Color.cyan);
        else if (source == bbutton) setBackground(Color.orange);
        else if (source == cbutton) setBackground(Color.magenta);
        else if (source == dbutton) setBackground(Color.yellow);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt){

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt){

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt){

    }
}

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame{
    public ButtonFrame(){
        setTitle("Low-level Mouse Event to Set Color");
        setSize(50, 50);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){ System.exit(0);}
        });
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new ButtonPanel());
    }
}

public class ME_SetColor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The new requirement is to exclude `extends JPanel` and any other extensions for `class ButtonPanel`. So the modified class has to be 
    `class ButtonPanel implements MouseListener{
        private JButton abutton, bbutton, cbutton, dbutton;`

Without JPanel, the ButtonPanel class would not be a component and therefore it can not be added to `contentPane`. Is there another way to make this ButtonPanel a component so it can be added to `contentPane`? Or is there any other ways to implement this program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Without JPanel, the ButtonPanel class would not be a component

You could extend JComponent. JComponent is the base class for Swing components. JPanel itself is a simple extension of JComponent (with one minor difference: a JPanel's `opaque` property is true by default, whereas it's false by default for JComponent).

But if your requirement is to exclude *any* extensions for ButtonPanel, you're right, you can't actually make it a component that can be added to a container.

However, you could include a component as a field of ButtonPanel:

```
class ButtonPanel implements ... {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton abutton, bbutton, cbutton, dbutton;

    ...

    public JPanel getPanel() { return panel; }
}
```

Then in ButtonFrame:

```
add(new ButtonPanel().getPanel());
```

You don't need to call `getContentPane()` and `contentPane.add` by the way, as a frame's own `add` methods [automatically do this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29).